# SQL Function is INCREDIBLY slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, query-optimization, sql-function

I have a SQL function that is used to return a single value in another view, this function takes well over 30 seconds sometimes on larger databases, I think it might be running over and over?

Honestly I'm just losing my mind at this point and need the help. Does anyone know the best way to optimize this?

The T-SQL function looks like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Base.fn_AssetPriority') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION Base.fn_AssetPriority
GO

CREATE FUNCTION Base.fn_AssetPriority 
    (@LID BIGINT)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(20)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Priority NVARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @RGID     BIGINT
    DECLARE @CP TABLE 
                (
                    ConsequenceAssessmentID BIGINT,
                    [Sign] VARCHAR(2),
                    Score DECIMAL(18,2),
                    AssetPriority CHAR(1),
                    ConsNo INT
                )

    SET @Priority = 'Not Allocated'

    INSERT INTO @CP
        SELECT  
            ConsequenceAssessmentID, [Sign], Score, AssetPriority, ConsNo
        FROM    
            Base.ConsequencePriority
        ORDER BY
            ConsNo DESC
   
    SELECT @RGID = MAX(ID)
    FROM ACA.ReviewGroup

    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @CP) 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @CAID BIGINT
        DECLARE @ConsNo INT
        DECLARE @Sign VARCHAR(2)
        DECLARE @Score DECIMAL(18,2)
        DECLARE @AP CHAR(1)

        SELECT TOP 1
            @CAID   = ConsequenceAssessmentID,
            @ConsNo = ConsNo,
            @Sign   = [Sign],
            @Score  = Score,
            @AP     = AssetPriority
        FROM    
            @CP
        ORDER BY
            ConsNo DESC

        IF @Sign = '=' 
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ACA.ConsequenceAssessment 
                       WHERE LID = @LID AND RGID = @RGID 
                         AND BaseCAID = @CAID AND Score = @Score) 
            BEGIN
                SET @Priority = @AP
                BREAK
            END
        END
        ELSE BEGIN
            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ACA.ConsequenceAssessment 
                       WHERE LID = @LID AND RGID = @RGID 
                         AND BaseCAID = @CAID AND Score >= @Score) 
            BEGIN
                SET @Priority = @AP
                BREAK
            END
        END

        DELETE FROM @CP 
        WHERE ConsequenceAssessmentID = @CAID 
          AND ConsNo = @ConsNo
    END

    RETURN @Priority
END
```

There is another view that calls this as a field:

```
    Base.fn_AssetPriority(BaseAS.ID) AS AssetPriority,
```

How on Earth do I optimize this? or get it to run a bit quicker?

Comment: I'm not surprised, if I am honest, it's a multi-line scalar function with a `WHILE`. SQL is a set based language, you want to use set based methods. I recommend rewriting this as as **inline** table value function.

Comment: That's a lot of logic to bury in a function in a view! Your route towards improving this is to obtain or create a functional spec for the logic in the function, then figure out how to rewrite the function so it's much simpler. Getting rid of the table-valued local variable `@CP` might help.  Then run the SELECTs in the function one-by-one in SSMS and look at their actual execution plans.

Comment: Quite probably all of that could be accomplished in a single query using *window functions* to determine the applicable @Priority which would be orders of magnitude faster, especially if using and inllined table-valued function.

Comment: Thanks for the advice folks!

Going to try re-write this function as inline table, join on the other end and hopefully that eliminates the issue.

Will reply and answer with the same script redone when complete to close off this question.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the execution plan for your stored function is stale.

Try doing this and rerunning it.

```
 EXEC sp_recompile N'Base.fn_AssetPriority';
```

If it gets faster you may want to run that recompile every so often. Maybe use a job to recompile it every day.

You probably don't want to put `WITH RECOMPILE` in the function's definition, because you use it a lot and the reason for recompilation is changing statistics in the tables it queries.